# How to add a vue data binding to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my code I create a lot of elements dynamicly on serverside, store the html of these elements in a javascript object,remove them and dynamicly/conditionally add them to different parts of the page.

For one particular element I want a data binding, such that I can refer to that binding in a `v-if` directive. However, if I add the `v-bind` on the server side, it gets lost after I copy the html.

Since I do only add the elements in my javascript code, I can not register the v-bind in my template. Neither can I provide the content in a component, since it is not static but relys on the input from the server.

How do I register the binding?

Sample Code:

Dynamicly generated form elements (server side):

```
<div id="archive" style="display: none;">
   <div><input type="text" name="purpose" v-bind:value="purpose" id="id_purpose"></div> <!-- v-bind has no effect -->
   <div><input type="text" name="purpose__iexact" id="id_purpose__iexact"></div>
   <div><input type="text" name="purpose__contains" id="id_purpose__contains"></div>
   <div><input type="text" name="purpose__icontains" id="id_purpose__icontains"></div>
   <div><input type="text" name="purpose__in" id="id_purpose__in"></div>
   ...
</div>
```

Code to copy the html:

```
    var input = {};
    var archive = document.getElementById('archive');
    for(var i = 0; i < archive.children.length; i++) {
        var div = archive.children[i];
        input[div.firstChild.name] = div.innerHTML
    }
    archive.parentNode.removeChild(archive);
```

Template code to display a certain input field dynamicly (client side):

```
<div class="inline" v-html="input[SOME CONDITIONAL COMPUTATIONS]"></div>
```

Comment: I think you should post sample code. By the way, you should render elements in template instead script if possible, you can binding dynamic data to state or computed and then use v-for/v-if to render it in <template></template>

Comment: Well i think its better for you to utilize vue components, it will be much easier to bind some data

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to rendering vue scene is:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Add new item" @click="addItem">
    <hr>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in data" :key="index">
      <span v-html="item.html"></span>
      <h3>Model data {{item.model}}</h3>
      <input type="text" v-model="item.model">
      <input type="button" value="Click me" @click="item.action(index)">
      <input v-if="item.show" type="button" value="Remove me" @click="removeItem(index)">
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        model: "",
        show:true,
        html: "<b>mydata html</b>",
        action: function(index) {
          console.log(`Clicked ${index} element.`);
        }
      },
      data: [
        {
          model: "",
          show:false,
          html: "<b>mydata html</b>",
          action: function(index) {
            alert(`Clicked ${index} element.`);
            console.log(`Clicked ${index} element.`);
          }
        },
        {
          model: "",
          show:true,
          html: "<b>mydata html</b>",
          action: function(index) {
             alert(`Clicked ${index} element.`);
            console.log(`Clicked ${index} element.`);
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      let item = Object.assign({}, this.item); // other way dublicating Observer
      this.data.push(item);
    },
    removeItem(index){
      this.data.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can add a show boolean prop to item object and v-if="" atribut to div to hide it.
I hope this example will help you.